# Not able to focus after clearing the input values from clear all icon in 'react-select'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select, onfocus

I have this issue https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/2793

only in Safari, ios devices other than the desktop. 
In my project I use create-react-app.

Even if you open their demo here https://react-select.com/components in your iPhone safari you will see the issue. Can you suggest me any temporary/permanent solution to this?

Comment: Removing setTimeout in https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/blob/77ae92885cdf73fd9def359379f7e08d68f5f849/src/Select.js#L932  will solve the problem. But is that the right solution? And the commit message was also not clear.